# How can i stop overfilling this array with random values?

Tags: java, arrays, indexoutofboundsexception

Im trying to fill apples with values from 0-99 and only want to use 20 spaces in the array and then print it out to the console. I keep getting indexOutOfBoundsException errors on line 18.

I've tried to set banana to stop the while loop but I keeps filling the array.

```
import java.util.Random;

public class arrayFill {
    private int[] apples = new int [20];

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        arrayFill obj = new arrayFill();
        Random rand = new Random();
        arrayFill pear = new arrayFill();
        int banana = -1;
        int orange = -1;
        while(banana != 0) {
            orange = rand.nextInt(100);
            banana = pear.apples[20];
        }
        System.out.println(apples);
    }
}
```

I want to output apples array with 20 random values but I always get this error.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 20
at arrayFill.main(arrayFill.java:19)
```

Comment: Quick guess: you have an array `int [20]`, which gives elements 0-19. You then have `pear.apples[20]`, which would be one beyond the end of the array. You probably need `pear.apples[19]`.

Comment: Is there a reason you're using fruits as variable names? Poor naming makes code hard to read and reason about, making bugs less obvious.

Comment: @duskwuff I just felt like using fruits

Answer (score 0):

I am gonna guess you are relatively new to programming. If all you are trying to do is create an array of size 20 and populate it with numbers 0-99, then your code is way more complicated than it needs to be. This is all you need:

```
import java.util.*;
public class arrayFill {
  public static final void main(String[] args){
    int[] apples = new int[20];
    Random rand = new Random();
    //Populating the array
    for(int i = 0; i < apples.length; i++){
        apples[i] = rand.nextInt(99);
    }
    //Printing out the array
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(apples));
  }
}
```

Comment: I made a mistake. The assignment that I have to do says numbers 1-100. I don't know how I didn't realize that. Is there a way to easily do that?

Comment: Just add +1 to the given answer, so: `rand.nextInt(99)+1`

Answer (score 0):

Like KevinO already mentioned in a comment, you get the ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException because of `pear.apples[20]` which refernces the 21st object.

Actually you don't need orange to fill your apples. Add `banana++` at the end of your while-loop, and replace your condition to `banana != 19`.

I suggest, you should try out some combinations in your code. For example initially set your banana to 0, use < and > as comparison operators. By doing that you learn how your code works.